# error running xUnit tests in Visual Studio 2015 with ReSharper Ultimate 10 using "xUnit.net Test Support for ReSharper 10"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xunit.net, resharper-10.0

This is what I currently have installed:

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 1
- ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2
- "xUnit.net Test Support for ReSharper 10" ReSharper extension (link
  to it on GitHub: https://github.com/xunit/resharper-xunit)

xUnit versions in my solution:

- xUnit version: 2.1.0
- xunit.runner.dnx: 2.1.0-rc1-build204

Here is the message I receive when trying to run any method decorated with [Fact] via resharper test runner:
[image]

I'm not too sure how to go about fixing it. I can still use the VS test runner, but I have ReSharper, and would rather use that. The extension I installed is written by and supported by xUnit, so not too sure if the bug is with the extension, ReSharper, Visual Studio, or xUnit versions....

I intalled xUnit.net Test Support for ReSharper 10 via ReSharper Extension Manager... here is a screegrab:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: did you nuget installed the resharper xunit plugin? can be addded directly from jetbrain https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/xunitcontrib/

Comment: Robi-y, I just edited my question to answer you question. In short, I used ReSharper's Extension Manger to install the plug-in, not nuget.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper 10 and 2016.1 (aka 10.1) doesn't support tests in DNX projects. The project system is very different, and doesn't always write the assembly to disk, and of course everything's changing since RC1. We're going to add support after RC2 is released, and things have stabilised a little.